# Replacing values in the dataframe keeping original values

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe as show below.

```
+------+----+----+
| col1 |col2|col3| 
+------+----+----+
|abc   | c  |h   |
|abc   | c  |h   |
|abc   | c  |h   |
+------+----+----+
```

for the col2 I have a value c as shown in the above picture.

Now for all the c values should be replaced with cat and h which is the value of col3 should be replaced with hat.

I can achieve this easily with the below statement

```
dataframe.withColumn("col2", when(col("col2").equalTo("c"), "cat").otherwise(col("col2") )
```

but I want to have the original values also . Like say my final dataframe should be looked as shown below

```
+------+----+----+-----+----+
| col1 |col2|col3| col4|col5|
+------+----+----+-----+----+
|abc   | c  |cat |    h|hat |
|abc   | c  |cat |    h|hat |
|abc   | c  |cat |    h|hat |
+------+----+----+----+-----+
```

How can I achieve this ???
Any help....:)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to give a new column name as

```
dataframe.withColumn("col4",
   when(col("col2").equalTo("c"), "cat").otherwise(col("col2") 
)
.withColumn("col5",
   when(col("col3").equalTo("c"), "cat").otherwise(col("col3") 
)
```

`withColumn` creates a new `column` with the name you provide. If the name already exist, it simply replaces the old column.

Output:

```
+------+----+----+-----+----+
| col1 |col2|col4| col3|col5|
+------+----+----+-----+----+
|abc   | c  |cat |    h|hat |
|abc   | c  |cat |    h|hat |
|abc   | c  |cat |    h|hat |
+------+----+----+----+-----+
```

If you really want to preserve the previous column you need to make a temp column and swap the column names.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If i'm not mistaken, you need to specify another column name in `withColumn` statement:

`withColumn("newcolumnname", ....`

This way the old column will be preserved and a new one will be created